# Export complete Trace32 watch window data to the text file during runtime

Tags: c, embedded, trace32, lauterbach

I have total 100 variables which are continuously updated in Trace32 during runtime. I wanted to export all the 100 variables to text file continuously during runtime. I have used below mentioned commands to export watch window variables to a text file, but only few watch variables are exported to the text file.

```
1) PRinTer.OPEN "~~~/varwatch.txt" ASCIIE
2) WinPRT <window name>
3) PRinTer.CLOSE
```

How can we export complete Trace32 watch window data to the text file during runtime?

Please refer the link: [Access watch variables from trace32 scripting language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57009893/20048915)

Answer (score 1):

Open the watch window super wide and use `WinPRT <window name> /ALL`.

Without the option **/ALL** only the visible part of your watch window will be printed (to file).

To open the window super wide use `WinPOS ,,1000.` before the command `Var.Watch`.

By the way: By using the command WinPOS you can specify the "window name" of your watch window.

Putting all together you get.:

```
WinPOS ,,1000.,,,,myWatchWindow
Var.Watch
Var.AddWatch %Decimal x y z
Var.AddWatch %Open 1 myStruct
PRinTer.OPEN "~~~/varwatch.txt" ASCIIE
WinPRT myWatchWindow
PRinTer.CLOSE
WinCLEAR myWatchWindow
```

Comment: Sir, Thanks a lot. I will try this solution.

Also I tried the below option and it worked for me.

''We need to right click on variable->format-> Choose E-> Set as default-> Ok''
this enables memory access to updated variable values while the ECU is running. Then used below commands to store the watch window data to .txt file,                                                                                     
1)PRinTer.OPEN "~~~/varwatch.txt" ASCIIE
2)WinPRT var.watch /ALL
3)PRinTer.CLOSE