# Get the Stack frame in Lauterbach T32 from Python RCL Api

Tags: python, trace32, lauterbach

I am trying to get the Call Stack from my python script over the API. Reading variables and setting breakpoints is not a problem, but I cannot read the Call stack or the current frame with the RCL library.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello Tobi, what exactly are you trying to achieve? You can export the `Frame.view` window similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73850398/export-complete-trace32-watch-window-data-to-the-text-file-during-runtime.